# How Do I Change Some Of The Default Shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm from windows background and I find it more easy to use `win key + D` to get my desktop. But in Ubuntu 12.04 it is `ctrl + win key + D`. I wish to change this.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to system settings (click the power button on the top right on Ubuntu 12.04 desktops to access the System Settings menu), click keyboard, then the shortcuts tab, under Navigation, look for 'Hide all normal windows' set it and your good to go.

Comment: is there is command line method ?

Comment: I think it can be done using gconftool, I just dont know how.  Gconftool allows you to change settings via the command line.  Hopefully it'll be a start for you.

Comment: I will definitely do some research on this and I will also post it here as a answer!