# What is the app that does the SHOW DESKTOP action

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, xfwm4, xfdesktop

There is an icon on an Xfce panel to show the desktop. The shortcut is set to Control-Alt-D. What is the application that does that job? I want to assign it to another keybinding.

Comment: i don't know if it's an app, but you can change the shortcut on `Settings > WIndow Manager > Keyboard`

Comment: If you wanna change the keyboard shortcute, take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136622/how-do-i-change-some-of-the-default-shortcuts) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts), they may help, and i don't know if there is a process for showing the desktop.

Comment: yes, just successfully changed ctrl-alt-d for win+d, Thanks! @bistoco

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard > Show Desktop`. Double-click on it and change default shortcut.